# Which muscles you need to train additionally for climbing to avoid unbalances?

Tags: rock-climbing, training

Climbing strongly trains your upper back, your forearms, biceps, legs and upper back. (http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/muscles-worked-during-rock-climbing-3416.html) However,
if you don't pay any attention to your training effort you might get a *climber's back* or suffer other injuries due to an unbalanced muscle structure.

**Which muscles you need to train additionally for climbing to avoid unbalances?**

Comment: @Liam is correct. This is a duplicate. I'm glad my answer matches up with the accepted answer from the original post, though!

Answer (score 0):

Always train antagonizing muscle groups for best attempts at maintaining balance. In other words, if you are training a muscle that moves your body in one direction, train the muscles that will move it back into the original position.

Biceps flex your arm - Triceps extend them.
Forearms flex your wrists - your Extensors raise them back into place.
Etcetera.

This opposing force strength training will keep certain imbalances in check. However, you should also stretch all of your muscle groups well. This will prevent injuries and imbalances also.